# Firestore DB: Create collection inside a document using REST API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an app that requires me to create a new collection inside existing document. I know it can be done on the firestore DB with a few clicks.

I want to do the same with a REST API

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rwH2.png)

Is there any way to implement this using a REST API

Thanks!

I tried looking for docs in the official website but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Firebase realtime db and Authentication are different services so please use the tags related to your query only. A collection will be automatically created when you add a document. Have you checked https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked the link that you gave and it outlines the basic steps to create a document under a collection. What I'm trying to do is a bit different. I'm trying to create a new collection inside an existing document. Is there any way to do it with REST API? ```collections>document>collection```

Comment: @Dharmaraj to explain it more clearly I'm trying to create a nested document using a rest api call. I'm able to do it manually and perhaps one can do it using js. Since I'm coding a project that requires rest api, I'm required to simulate it using that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a subcollection using the firestore REST API, use the url below.

**NB// Replace all variables that start with** `YOUR`

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>/databases/(default)/documents/<YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME>/<YOUR_DOCUMENT_ID>/<YOUR_SUBCOLLECTION_NAME>?documentId=<YOUR_RANDOM_ID>
```

Also, use the json example below for the request body because this is a `POST` request.

```
{
  "fields":{
    "name":{
      "stringValue":"This is a new document in a subcollection"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create the subcollection using an API call? Or is it something that firebase doesn't allow??

Comment: Do you mean creating a subcollection without a document using the firestore REST API?

Comment: Let's say i have a collection namely users. I have documents a,b, and c. is there a way to create collection inside this document using a REST API>>

Comment: You can only create a collection using the firebase sdk or the firestore REST API.

Comment: Yes, i need the endpoint for creating firestore collection with a REST API. I looked at the documentation but couldn't find anything. Can you share me if you have?

Comment: The answer above will create a collection inside a document using the REST API, but you cannot create a collection without a document, you can only create a collection with a document inside that particular collection.